# Basic File Reading to Array Storage

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, collections, methods

I have a simple Java questions and I need a simple answer, if possible.  I need to input the data from the file and store the data into an array.  To do this, I will have to have the program open the data file, count the number of elements in the file, close the file, initialize your array, reopen the file and load the data into the array.  I am mainly having trouble getting the file data stored as an array. Here's what I have:

The to read file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ylb3iloj9af7qz/scores.txt

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;


public class StandardizedScore8
{



//Accounting for a potential exception and exception subclasses
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    // TODO a LOT
    String filename;
    int i=0;


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nEnter the file name:");
    filename=scan.nextLine();



    File file = new File(filename);


    //File file = new File ("scores.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file);

    String [] fileArray = new String [filename];
    //Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new File ("scores.txt"));

    //User-input
//  System.out.println("Reading from 'scores.txt'");
//  System.out.println("\nEnter the file name:");
//  filename=scan.nextLine();

    //File-naming/retrieving
//  File file = new File(filename);
//  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can if you don't care about the trouble of doing things twice. Use `while(inputFile.hasNext()) i++;`

to count the number of elements and create an array:

```
String[] scores = new String[i];
```

If you do care, use a list instead of an array:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while(inputFile.hasNext()) list.add(inputFile.next());
```

You can get list elements like `list.get(i)`, set list element like `list.set(i,"string")` and get the length of list `list.size()`.

By the way, your line of `String [] fileArray = new String [filename];`is incorrect. You need to use an int to create an array instead of a String.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use a Collection. This way, you don't have to know the size of the file beforehand and you'll read it only once, not twice. The Collection will manage its own size.

Comment: I would prefer not to use them, as I do not know how I'd manipulate it later on in methods.  Would it be feasible to use an array at all?  --Would I need to know how many items are in the file?

Comment: You definitely should use a List/Collection. If you don't know how to manipulate them, now would be a great time to learn. They're very easy to use (easier than arrays) and reading the documentation makes learning easy: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 * Do it the easy way using a List
 *
 */

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nEnter the file name:");
    String filename = scan.nextLine();

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String thisLine = reader.readLine();

    while (thisLine != null) {
        lineList.add(thisLine);
        thisLine = reader.readLine();
    }

    // test it

    int i = 0;
    for (String testLine : lineList) {
        System.out.println("Line " + i + ": " + testLine);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: From the homework tag: *Homework means the question is requesting help with school homework. This lets potential answerers know that they SHOULD guide the student in solving the problem, and SHOULD NOT simply show the complete answer.*

Comment: darn... missed the tag. sorry about that. if they haven't covered lists in his class he probably won't be able to use my answer anyways.

Comment: Thanks anyway, we don't cover lists on the class (although they would be helpful).

Answer (score 1):

We can use the ArrayList collection to store the values from the file to the array without knowing the size of the array before hand.
You can get more info on ArrayList collections from the following urls.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=234

Comment: Thanks a lot, although more practical examples would be useful.